# Is there a way to order the ggplot2 facet_grid subplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently generating a comparative plot of predictor algorithms using ggplot2 `facet_grid`. Is there a way to specify the ordering of the subplots? in my case I am interested in seeing them by MSE in ascending order. How can I do that? reading the `facet_grid` documentation doesn't ring any bells.

The plotting code looks like this:

```
ggplot(df_all, mapping=aes(x=t, y=value, color=label, shape=label)) +  
   geom_point() + ggtitle('Test vs. Predicted') + theme(legend.position='none') + facet_grid(. ~ group) + 
geom_segment(data=df_error_all, aes(x=df_error_all$x,y=df_error_all$y,xend=df_error_all$xend,yend=df_error_all$yend), size=0.3) + 
geom_segment(data=df_arrow_all, aes(x=df_arrow_all$x,y=df_arrow_all$y,xend=df_arrow_all$xend,yend=df_arrow_all$yend), size=0.3)
```

Comment: From `?facet_grid` near the very top of the examples: "To change plot order of facet grid, change the order of variable levels with factor()
"

Comment: See [this](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) and [this](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot-revisited/).  This has nothing to do with ggplot but your factor levels.

Comment: Oh, and _never_ use `$` inside `aes()`. The whole point of specifying `data = df_arrow_all` is that `aes()` evaluates `x = x` within that data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @joran and others have mentioned, facet_grid ordering is based on the levels of the factor column.

You can use `relevel` to change the order. (Either modifying the original column or creating a new one)

```
df_all[["newGroup"]] <- relevel(df_all[["group"]], "value1")

##  OR: 
df_all[["group"]] <- relevel(df_all[["group"]], "value1")
```

#### UPDATE:

I have the following function in my utils file, which once I bumped into `relevel` I had thought was superfluous.  But as @DWin points out in the comments below, `relevel` does not work with more than one level as a value for `ref`.

In those situations, `setFactorOrder` will likely be useful

```
setFactorOrder <- function(x, order=sort(levels(x))) { 
# Returns a factor ordered by `order`.  
# If order is missing, defaults to `levels(x)` if available, else to `sort(unique(x))`
# Useful for ggplot and elsewhere were ordering is based on the order of the levels

  if (!is.factor(x)) {
    warning("`x` is not a factor. Will coerce.")
    levs <- sort(unique(x))
    if (missing(order))
      order <- levs
  } else {
    levs <- levels(x)
  }

  # any values in order, not in levels(x)
  NotInx <- setdiff(order, levs)

  if (length(NotInx)) {
    warning ("Some values not in x:\n", paste(NotInx, collapse=", "))
  }

  # levels(x) not explicitly named in order
  Remaining <-  setdiff(levs, order)

  order <- c(setdiff(order, NotInx), Remaining)

  factor(x, level=order)
}
```

#### Notice that you have to assign the results of `setFactorOrder`, as in:

```
x <- setFactorOrder(x, c("value1", "value2"))

# or
df_all[["group"]] <- setFactorOrder(df_all[["group"]], c("Ketchup", "Catsup", "Mustard"))
```

Comment: Huh? When I use `relevel` with more than one element in the ref argument, I get an error (which the help page suggests is the intended behavior.)

Comment: @Ricardo looks great. How can I sort my factor levels c('dummy', 'algo1', 'algo2') based on their MSE e.g. c(0.4, 0.3, 0.01) using your function?

Comment: you simply need to send the function whatever ordering you would like.  You can first order your levels using the (base R) `order` function.  Have a look: `?order`.   You might need something like `setFactorOrder(x, order=values[order(values)] )`